# Implementation/Tools for upsampling cartoon video and imagery

Tags: software-recommendation

I recently discovered a [paper on upsampling video](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Fast-gradient-aware-upsampling-for-cartoon-video-Yan-Shen/19f8a43cdeb33713eccf96981d4050dd6b10058e) that introduced a novel method for the case cartoon and other line-based video/imagery works. Given that the paper was from 2010, I would have expected to find some sort of tooling that would enable the use of this method, but have been unable to find such implementations. Has anyone seen this or other methods for upsampling such imagery used in production? Do such tools exist yet?

Comment: Perhaps you should contact the authors of the paper.